# jQuery animation not working in anchor tags or anchor tag children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've spent the better part of a day tracking down a problem I've been having with jQuery animation.  There appear to be issues with applying jQuery.animate() to anchor elements, or to child elements inside of anchor elements, at least with regard to movement animations.  I've boiled the problem down to a fairly simple example which illustrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var foo = {};

        function TestMove(newx, newy) {
            this.newx = newx;
            this.newy = newy;
        }

        TestMove.prototype = {
            movex:function () {
                $("#newsec").animate({left: this.newx + "px"});
            },
            movey:function () {
                $("#newsec").animate({top: this.newy + "px"});
            }
        }

        function bar() {
            foo[1].movex();
            foo[1].movey();
        }

        function init() {
            foo[1] = new TestMove(200,200);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <a href="" style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: red;" id="newsec" onclick="bar()"></div>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

The animation doesn't work, regardless of whether I put the id attribute and onclick event handler call in the <a> tag or in the <div> within it.  If, on the other hand,I remove the <a> element tags altogether, the animation works as expected on the <div> element.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

The issue is almost moot, since I can easily do with <div> elements in the working page what I could also do with <a> elements.  In the working code (much more complex) I'm using event.preventDefault() on the anchor elements so that linking and other actions are driven by explicit event handlers and this can be done from a <div> just as well.  I believe I can even change the pointer icon when one does a mouseover on the <div> so that it mimics a true anchor in this regard as well.

Comment: Just a suggestion - use a .click() jquery event (or .on() if the content is not static)

Comment: Also, does this happen every time on load?  If so, you don't need an event the first time, just do it after the page loads in  a .load(function(){ /* code here */ });

Comment: [The animation seems to work fine, if you cancel the click on the anchor](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dHcBe/) -- I'm unable to see how it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the browser is going to the anchor prior to the animation being put in place.  There are plugins to get around these sort of issues, or you can put together your own.

http://briangonzalez.org/arbitrary-anchor

Example of a simple implementation:

```
 jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")
            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;

            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Stefano D seems to have nailed it.  Adding code to disable the default event handler for the anchor tag allows the click to fall through to the enclosed div and the code works.  I though I had this taken care of on the production page, but I obviously need to revisit the code with this in mind.